# Angular, testing select with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to test out a case when the select changes and I seem to be having problems - Here's what I have

The test -

```
describe('Unit: MainCtrl', function() {
 // Load the module with MainCtrl
 beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  var ctrl, scope;
  // inject the $controller and $rootScope services
  // in the beforeEach block
 beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
// Create a new scope that's a child of the $rootScope
scope = $rootScope.$new();
// Create the controller
ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
  $scope: scope
});

 }));

 it('should create $scope.myPass when type of pass is selected and purchasePass is run', 
function() {
  expect(scope.myPass).toBeUndefined();
  select('itemSelected').option(0);
  scope.purchasePass();
  expect(scope.myPass).toEqual(5);
 });
})
```

And inside the template I have

```
<select ng-model="itemSelected"  ng-options="item as item.name for item in selectItems"> </select>
```

And this is giving me back the error -

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: select

Says I don't have variable select, but I am unsure what I am doing wrong to cause this. Would very much appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> select('itemSelected').option(0);

where did you get this functions "select" and "option"?

If you want to change value, you can directly change it on the scope:

```
scope.itemSelected = 1;
scope.$digest(); // if you have $watch, and want to trigger it
```

Comment: I think the `select/option` is Protractor syntax for E2E tests, which isn't available in Jasmine unit tests.

Comment: No, Protractor does not have `select/option` methods. It has different methods like `element(by.tagName('select'))`, `element(by.css('select option'))`

Comment: @lamStalker AngularJS